# Removing strange characters from string copied to clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

hi guys so I have a textarea that is being used by CodeMirror. However,
when I copy any line and paste it, weird characters are being copied

`€‹copiedstring`

the thing is there is nothing in the text that contains `€‹` and that this is not consistent. I don't know where its coming from.

So my solution is to study the copied text, scan it for the strange characters, and remove it so that when they pastes it it is guaranteed it wont have those characters.

Comment: Please post [mre]

Comment: the thing is its really unpredictable. i dont know where its coming from and i would like to edit the text being copied somehow to remove the euro sign

Comment: ive updated the question to reflect the changes, i am looking for a clipboard solution.

Comment: you can do something like this I think: `editor.on('copy', (editor, e) => {})`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser or CodeMirror. Try reporting it but only if you can find out the definitive sequence of steps to reproduce the bug in a new browser profile without extensions. It's also unclear why you added `google-chrome-extension` tag: either clarify how it's related and show the code or remove the tag.